# Find this closed form $\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\lfloor a_{k}\rfloor +\lfloor a_{k}+\frac{1}{2}\rfloor \right)$

Tags: summation, ceiling-and-floor-functions

Let $\dfrac{1}{a_{k}}=\dfrac{1}{k^2}+\dfrac{1}{k^2+1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{(k+1)^2-1}$

I need some ideas to exploit for finding the closed form of
$$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\left(\lfloor a_{k}\rfloor +\lfloor a_{k}+\dfrac{1}{2}\rfloor \right)$$
we get 
$$\dfrac{2k+1}{k^2+2k}<\dfrac{1}{a_{k}}<\dfrac{2k+1}{k^2}$$
Therefore 
$$\dfrac{k^2}{2k+1}<a_{k}<\dfrac{k^2+2k}{2k+1}$$

Comment: A possibly useful fact (easy to prove):
$$\lfloor 2x\rfloor=\lfloor x\rfloor+\lfloor x+\frac12\rfloor.$$ Not sure it helps, but it might.

Comment: interesting idea,Now we only find $[2a_{k}]$ closed form

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let
$$b_{n}=\dfrac{1}{n^2}+\dfrac{1}{n^2+1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^2+n-1}+\dfrac{1}{n^2+n}+\dfrac{1}{n^2+n+1}+\cdots+\dfrac{1}{n^2+2n}$$
so
$$\dfrac{2}{n+1}<\dfrac{1}{n}+\dfrac{1}{n+2}=\dfrac{n+1}{n^2+n}+\dfrac{n}{n^2+2n}<b_{n}<\dfrac{n}{n^2}+\dfrac{n+1}{n^2+n}=\dfrac{2}{n}$$
so we have
$$\dfrac{2}{k+1}<\dfrac{1}{a_{k}}<\dfrac{2}{k}$$
so
$$k<2a_{k}<k+1$$
so
$$\lfloor 2a_{k}\rfloor =k$$
so use indenity
$$\lfloor a_{k}\rfloor +\lfloor a_{k}+\dfrac{1}{2}\rfloor=\lfloor 2a_{k}\rfloor=k$$

Comment: Elegant solution! +1